# Role base security on path

Tags: security, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have security defined all the routes /CONTEXT_PATH/** has role Admin

Now I want to add /CONTEXT_PATH/WRITE/** has ROLE "WRITE"  Does spring allow the person who has ROLE write but not admin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You just need to define

`/CONTEXT_PATH/WRITE/** has ROLE "WRITE"`

before

`/CONTEXT_PATH/** has role Admin`